# Angular minimized viewport div on full width on page

Tags: css, angular

I would like to have a div that is on the site's full width, even when the page is minimized. When it's minimized it has a scrollbar for the things which doesn't fit on the x-axis.

There I have a div which should be the full width with a little margin on the right and left sides.
But it is just as wide as the viewport and when I scroll to the right, I see that it's not all the way to the right side.

```css
.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
    
.box { 
    margin: auto 10px;
    width: 100% 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` means 100 percent of parent element.

And since you have parent element wider than your viewport, use [`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units) units to define width relative to viewport

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 3000px;
}

.box { 
     margin: auto 10px;
     width: 100vw;
     background: #AFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```